# JBOSS error for installing a new software

Tags: java, maven, javafx, jboss

I am required to add to jboss a new software for javafx,

The required steps are like so:

1) Help - Install new software

2) Add

3) Name = xtext

4) Location= https://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/composite/releases/?fbclid=IwAR2ZllYdV_hEzQ-llcL49s3-fe1z6V--9GgjQXuhcSHYdG5DzVizNI59QpU

and repeat that for another link.
https://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/1.1.0/site/?fbclid=IwAR0c26OdkkwX212wIoWlCXAbP1lhJliQnobrNnudr3U-uNUAduDey7dG3qA

The first link worked fine, but the second link always finished with this error:

```
    An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=devstudio, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.core,1.1.0.201411050703.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 294952e5e63b271d7725cf47bff32151 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.core.guice,1.1.0.201411050703.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 3c4bd144d1b48d9b4e8c5bcaedef81e4 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.formats.svg,1.1.0.201411050703.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 511e84ee00debe7d6ac5a82db2ffac73 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.fx.ide.basic.feature,1.1.0.201411050807.
Downloaded stream not a valid archive. Check the server.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.converter,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 2d59e927d195fd40f75be0aaffcb0a29 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.fx.ide.converter.feature,1.1.0.201411050807.
Downloaded stream not a valid archive. Check the server.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.css,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 6d612e45522db39d306f27b80d2a02cf and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.cssext,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 1abc88e3e02708fa2e2a6748a2538bd2 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.cssext.proposals,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 2d4c85b0795a659c0de7dc81a120992f and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.cssext.ui,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 599db5e952c9cb23c3227df4eafc9016 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.feature,1.1.0.201411050807.
Downloaded stream not a valid archive. Check the server.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.jfx2,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: e3724c602bed76947cb4846fdaa14911 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.jfx8,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 1743c7aa97498f29ab31343637395d70 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.ui,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: dbe3ad2538e70a5babd6abb8cb87209c and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.fx.ide.feature,1.1.0.201411050807.
Downloaded stream not a valid archive. Check the server.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.fxgraph,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 2cddb593e6bd72ca2e37849fd3d9e49c and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.fx.ide.fxgraph.feature,1.1.0.201411050807.
Downloaded stream not a valid archive. Check the server.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.fxgraph.ui,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 70d89cd13ed32686c4cf2701d819e8e3 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.fxml,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: a3ed37af99c6ec1a4048ff6e4ceb0089 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.fxml.compiler,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: d9393be3f1fad2d8ae22aea2d03b2524 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.fx.ide.fxml.feature,1.1.0.201411050807.
Downloaded stream not a valid archive. Check the server.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.java6,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 5397a1ae45d3133d280cf18c091a5807 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.jdt.core,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: ed83d37563e565e3e922697e4c6129bc and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.jdt.ui,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 5f66d67ba49f18e3103c6c2cb9db9fbb and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.l10n,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: efbf41c78825e04c711cea88da2633fe and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.fx.ide.l10n.feature,1.1.0.201411050807.
Downloaded stream not a valid archive. Check the server.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.l10n.ui,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 3f9a29253304fa2e75df41171d310013 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.fx.ide.mobile.feature,1.1.0.201411050807.
Downloaded stream not a valid archive. Check the server.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.model,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: e003a14138c2a9e41c629cad0d459679 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.pde.core,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 655b572f777232a81cd4e50575be66fe and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.fx.ide.pde.feature,1.1.0.201411050807.
Downloaded stream not a valid archive. Check the server.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.pde.ui,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: f6314b21b83b9a03a971e76148994197 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.pde.ui.e4,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 75477d5bdd8292bcd38fbf21ea278b77 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.rrobot,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 73b85199634bb18af5b0114f4db288ee and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.rrobot.dsl,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 5e5b91ec98de52217cbd3699a7d86438 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.rrobot.dsl.ui,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 120bb87a29785224e0296f512c173b8b and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.fx.ide.rrobot.feature,1.1.0.201411050807.
Downloaded stream not a valid archive. Check the server.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.rrobot.model,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: c249709ecb4580218aa718604eb133c8 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.ui,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 7bec8e16ec20ae1c0afcf99304a4ef78 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.ui.mobile.sim.device,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 9d7e00f189685a0db3f990ebf7956f63 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.ui.mobile.sim.launch,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 3cb66e71f5d490ce73ab6962fee735d2 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ide.ui.preview,1.1.0.201411050807.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 08099ff89fe2bfc56489fc2a82f197e9 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.javafx,2.2.0.201411050602.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 9fc02623665fb1f7e4847e97ca68f5ee and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.osgi,1.1.0.201411050602.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: c22ffce1a6233158b9ae4ec7a8182b32 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.osgi.util,1.1.0.201411050703.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 713d5b45d56d53b0c0a0d9237d2cdcda and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ui.controls,1.1.0.201411050703.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 45a4fd127474ab9249ddfb1dc82cd857 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ui.mobile,1.1.0.201411050703.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8a1ed3818e2cafabd51d439174f08780 and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.ui.panes,1.1.0.201411050703.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: cbfbf349f6f37029affb1e7f5c8b076c and found e729784c17944196393bbaf689f68e48.
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second link, change https to http and it will work, then go to preferences then javafx then set the chose the scene builder app for the appropriate field.